# Extract key phrases for binary outcome

Tags: nlp, semi-supervised-learning

I have a set of phrases that lead to a binary outcome (accept/reject) and I was wondering what techniques are most helpful for extracting key phrases that are most likely to determine the outcome, given that I have a training set of data that has the English-language phrase and the observed outcome.

To illustrate the idea let me give a simple example:

### Accepted

- Sounds great
- That would be great
- That's fine

key words: great, fine

### Rejected

- I'm not sure
- I don't think so
- No way

key words: not, don't, no

Comment: Counterpoint: "Not bad at all!" "Great god, this is awful."

Comment: Very good point, I have run into similar such issues before. I think N-gram analysis can help this, perhaps starting at 3-grams for instance so that smaller phrases don't create conflicting scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of techniques that you could use, depending on what you would like to do.

If your goal is to **gain insight into the phrases** that are being used in each group, then I'd recommend looking for the most frequent [N-grams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) of different lengths that appear in each class. Here is a [related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128802/how-to-use-sklearns-countvectorizerand-to-get-ngrams-that-include-any-punctua) that shows how you can use `nltk` and `sklearn` to extract these.

If your goal is to **predict the outcome** (accept/reject) given a phrase, then I'd recommend setting this up as a binary classification problem. Since those phrases are quite short, you could start with a Bag of Words approach - the scikit-learn [documentation for working with text data](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html) is a good example that guides you through the steps.